# Great Common Division with Continued Fractions

Tags: continued-fractions

If I have this GCD equation:
$$89=16\cdot5+9\\
16=9\cdot1+7\\
9=7\cdot1+2\\
7=2\cdot3+1\\
2=1\cdot2+0$$

Then my continued fraction will be:

$[5: 1, 1, 3, 2]$

But if I will have this GCD equation:

$$300=99\cdot3+3\\
99=3\cdot33+0$$

Then my continued fraction will be:

$[3: 33]$

Is it possible for a continued fraction have only $2$ numbers in total (like the one stated above)?

Comment: Yes. Your example clearly proves that.

Comment: So how will the calculation of the continued fraction will look?

Comment: $\frac{300}{99} = 3 + \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @DarthGeek, shouldn't that be $\frac {300}{99} = 3+\frac 1 {33}$?

Comment: @Ragnar Yes, sorry. Typo.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it is perfectly fine for a continued fraction to contain only two numbers.

*Answered to get off the "unanswered" queue.*